# modify operation on XML column is taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance, xquery

How can I improve the performance of this query?

```
UPDATE  table1
SET xmlcol.modify('replace value of (/Root/Tag/text())[1]
                   with sql:variable("@NewValue")')
WHERE xmlcol.value('(/Root/Tag/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = @OldValue
```

There are nearly 95,000 rows in table1 and each contains 'Tag'.

Comment: How does the contents of this column look? How much time does it take? How often does it need to run?

Comment: add xml with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For increase your performance for Xml purpose, you can create a primary xml index then a secondary index for Value. see `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx`

Here is code example :

```
Create table XmlTest
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_XmlTest_XmlData PRIMARY kEY,
    XmlData xml
)
GO

Create primary Xml index IX_XML_Primary ON dbo.XmlTest(XmlData);
GO

Create xml index IX_XmlData_Secondary_Value ON dbo.XmlTest(XmlData)
USING XML INDEX IX_XML_Primary
FOR VALUE;
GO
```

Also, for xml query Sql server consume a lot of cpu resource for the query plan generating, so I would suggest you to use sp_executesql store procedure and use the query option KEEPFIXED PLAN. This will avoid sql to recreate a plan for different value and on statictics update.

Here is code example :

```
Declare @Query nvarchar(max);
Declare @QueryParemeters nvarchar(max);

Set @QueryParameters = '@In_NewValue nvarchar(max),@In_OldValue nvarchar(max)'

Set @Query ='UPDATE  table1
             SET xmlcol.modify(''replace value of (/Root/Tag/text())[1]
                   with sql:variable("@In_NewValue")'')
             WHERE xmlcol.value(''(/Root/Tag/text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(100)'') = @In_OldValue OPTION (KEEPFIXED PLAN)'

exec sp_executesql @stmt=@Query,@params=@QueryParameters,@In_NewValue=@NewValue,@In_OldValue=@OldValue
```

Hope it helps.